# clickable table row javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I tried to hook my link to a `<tr>` and made some like this:

```
<tr onlick=document.location.href='something.html'>
```

I do find it working but the thing is.. I want to make the link in a popup window and have this function..

```
function popit(url){
    newwindow = window.open(url, '', "status=yes, height=500; width=500; resizeable=no");
}
```

It's quite working fine when I applied it to some of my `<a>` but the thing is I cant use `popit(url)` function and at the same time use `onclick` attribute to a `<tr>`.

Comment: try this:
`<tr onclick="javascript:window.open('something.html', '', "status=yes, height=500; width=500; resizeable=no");">`

Comment: A little additional reading, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice

Comment: `onlick`? Just what kind of event are you expecting the browser to respond to!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to specify:

```
<tr onclick="popit('something.html')">
```

As long as the `popit()` function is a properly defined global function elsewhere in your javascript.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5rWep/

Comment: You beat me to it :). This is the same thing I wrote